# Get all the related fields in one json response

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

i want to make an api with laravel and i want to get all the fields like the following format

```
projects: [
   {
    id,
    name,
    logo,
    thumbnail,
    phases: [{
        id,
        name,
        date,
        views: [{
        id,
        name,
        thumbnail,
        images: [{
            id,
            path: [ 5 urls for the various images ]
            date
        }]
    }]
    }]
   }
   ]
```

my database model like the following 
- projects -> hasmany phases
- phases -> hasmany view
- views -> hasmany images

the model like the following

```
class Project extends \Eloquent {

// Add your validation rules here
public static $rules = [
    'title' => 'required',
];

// Don't forget to fill this array
protected $fillable = [ 'title', 'desc' ];

public function phases() {
    return $this->hasMany('Phase');
}

}


class Phase extends \Eloquent {
protected $fillable = [ 'title', 'from', 'to', 'project_id' ];

public static $rules = [
    'title' => 'required',
    'from'  => 'required',
    'to'    => 'required'
];

public function views() {
    return $this->hasMany( 'View' );
}

public function project(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Project');
}
}

class View extends \Eloquent {

// Add your validation rules here
public static $rules = [
    'title'      => 'required',
    'image_path' => 'required'
];

// Don't forget to fill this array
protected $fillable = [ 'title', 'image_path', 'caption', 'view_date', 'phase_id' ];

public function phase(){
    return $this->belongsTo('Phase');
}

}
```

How can i get all the json in the index response, i use the following but not getting the same format

```
Project::all();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to [eager load](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading) the datasets:

```
Project::with('phases.views','phases.images')->get();
```

Looks like you don't have the images in your model as a related model, but you do have projects. But your json example shows images and not projects, is this right?

Comment: about the image you right, i will add it lately but you for the idea

Answer (score 0):

Relationships aren't loaded by default when retrieving a collection (this is called lazy loading). But you can load them by using the `with()` method (this is called **eager loading**):

```
Project:all()->with('phases')->get();
```

You can also chain nested relationships with dot notation:

```
Project:all()->with('phases.views')->get();
```